# Anaconda: Unable to import pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, anaconda

I am unable to `import pylab` using the latest version of [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) (Linux 64 bit). Other packages seem to work fine. (Note: I don't have `sudo` access)

```
In [1]: import pylab as pl
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2cf12a0af6ff> in <module>()
----> 1 import pylab as pl

/home/josh/installs/conda/1.7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py in <module>()
----> 1 from matplotlib.pylab import *
      2 import matplotlib.pylab
      3 __doc__ = matplotlib.pylab.__doc__

/home/josh/installs/conda/1.7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py in <module>()
    267 from numpy.linalg import *
    268 
--> 269 from matplotlib.pyplot import *
    270 
    271 # provide the recommended module abbrevs in the pylab namespace

/home/josh/installs/conda/1.7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>()
     96 
     97 from matplotlib.backends import pylab_setup
---> 98 _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
     99 
    100 

/home/josh/installs/conda/1.7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.pyc in pylab_setup()
     23         backend_name = 'matplotlib.backends.%s'%backend_name.lower()
     24     backend_mod = __import__(backend_name,
---> 25                              globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
     26 
     27     # Things we pull in from all backends

/home/josh/installs/conda/1.7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py in <module>()
     11 
     12 from backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
---> 13 from backend_qt4 import QtCore, QtGui, FigureManagerQT, FigureCanvasQT,\
     14      show, draw_if_interactive, backend_version, \
     15      NavigationToolbar2QT

/home/josh/installs/conda/1.7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4.py in <module>()
     23     figureoptions = None
     24 
---> 25 from qt4_compat import QtCore, QtGui, _getSaveFileName, __version__
     26 
     27 backend_version = __version__

/home/josh/installs/conda/1.7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt4_compat.py in <module>()
     34 # Now perform the imports.
     35 if QT_API in (QT_API_PYQT, QT_API_PYQTv2):
---> 36     import sip
     37     if QT_API == QT_API_PYQTv2:
     38         if QT_API_ENV == 'pyqt':

ImportError: No module named sip
```

If I try

```
> conda install sip
```

I get:

```
Error: No packages found matching: sip
```

I also get errors with:

```
$ pip install sip                                                       1 
Downloading/unpacking sip
  You are installing a potentially insecure and unverifiable file. Future v
ersions of pip will default to disallowing insecure files.                
  Downloading sip-4.15.2.zip (899kB): 899kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package sip
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip_build_josh/
sip/setup.py'                                                             
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip_build_josh/sip/
setup.py'                                                                 

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build
_josh/sip                                                             
Storing complete log in /home/josh/.pip/pip.log
```

Any thoughts on why?

Comment: You seem to not have `PyQt` installed properly, use a different backend.

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell. What other backend would you recommmend?

Comment: The snarky (but mostly correct) answer is which ever one you have the dependencies installed for.  Try `tkagg`, `wxagg`, or `gtk3agg`

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend scroll down for the full list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just had this problem and it was related to which qt backend matplotlib was trying to use, try:

```
import PyQt4
```

If you don't have PyQt4 you probably have PySide

```
import PySide
```

If this is the case you need to set the `matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4'] == 'PySide'` not `'PyQt4'`. You can also do this in your matplotlibrc file (**~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc**)

```
# find and change line:
backend.qt4 : PySide
```

Note: if you don't have the matplotlibrc file you can copy it from the matplotlib source directory

```
import os
import matplotlib
mpl_dir = os.path.dirname(matplotlib.__file__)
os.system("cp {}/mpl-data/matplotlibrc ~/.matplotlib/".format(mpl_dir))
```

Comment: There is an open issue for Anaconda for this problem: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
```