# Anaconda: Attribute error while running pylab with anaconda distribution on Windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I am trying to import pylab and this is the code that I am writing.

```
import pylab

pylab.figure(1)
pylab.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,7,3,5])
pylab.show()
```

But I am getting the error that

```
File "E:\mitedx1\mitedx2\week1\pylab.py", line 2, in <module>
  import pylab
File "E:\mitedx1\mitedx2\week1\pylab.py", line 4, in <module>
pylab.figure(1)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'figure'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

I tried to take help from the answers provided here

[Anaconda: Unable to import pylab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231944/anaconda-unable-to-import-pylab)

but to no rescue. I have also checked the path with cmd, and it is showing the inclusion of C:\Anaconda and C:\Anaconda\Scripts there. What would be the solution to fix this problem?

Comment: May be you have a python script named pylab.py in the working directory , kindly check this issue ?

Comment: @Anmol_uppal, it is, the script name is in the error as per my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You called your script `pylab.py`, rename it to something else.

```
E:\mitedx1\mitedx2\week1\pylab.py # <- you are importing from this not the pylab module
```

Make sure to delete the `E:\mitedx1\mitedx2\week1\pylab.pyc` file also.

Comment: Thanks, it is no more showing that error but no new window is coming with the graph plot. Instead, it is showing me that "Qt: Untested Windows version 6.4 detected!". Is it because I am running it on Windows 10 or there is some other reason?

Comment: have a look here https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/135 seems to be a problem with Qt and windows 10, not overly surprising as windows 10 is just a prerelease. I would be wary of developing in a windows 10 os you may find lots of other things will not be compatible also

Comment: So this is the problem of OS and it would work in any other one!!

Comment: Yes, I don't think you would have an issue using another distribution.